# Getting laravel app pretty url on Nginx (homestead) working

Tags: laravel, homestead

[image]

trying to lunch a laravel site on a homestead setup with a pretty url: moziz.app. my host file : 192.168.10.10  moziz.app

all i get back is Your connection is not private with this:
[image]

Comment: are you trying https://moziz.app or http://moziz.app ?

if you try https obviously you dont have certificate but if you try http and you see this message then 80 port conf of nginx redirects you to https

Comment: remove the `s` in `https` in the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're accessing your local host with HTTP**S**. This might be caused by Chrome enforcing HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) for all `.app` domains (Google owns the `.app` TLD, so they can enforce this).

The easiest solution is to switch your domain to `moziz.test` (update your hosts file and Homestead.yaml), and then use `http://` instead of `https://`.

After changing the sites property in Homestead.yaml you might also need to run `vagrant reload --provision`.

Comment: @user2245190 did you also change the address in your browser from `https://` to `http://`?

Comment: Spot on. Thank you